Power BI Dax Filtering Question - Selecting all current and lower index values
i have the below table called "Skill Selection List":



Skill
Level




Writing
1


Writing
2


Writing
3


Writing
4


Reading
1


Reading
2


Reading
3


Reading
4


Listening
1


Listening
2


Listening
3


Listening
4


Speaking
1


Speaking
2


Speaking
3


Speaking
4



i have created a slicer with the combination of the two columns from the "Skill Selection List" Table.
i want to create a measure that returns a dynamic table , where if i select, for example, Speaking 3 and Listening 2, the measure will return a table of Speaking 1, 2, 3 and Listening 1, Listening 2

Try this:

Create the following measure.
Add Measure to your table visual's filters as Show items when value is 1

Measure:
ShowRow = 
var slicerVals = ALLSELECTED(Slicer[Value]) //Get all selected Values
var addSkillLevel = ADDCOLUMNS(slicerVals, "Level", CONVERT(RIGHT([Value], LEN([Value]) - SEARCH(" ", [Value])), INTEGER)) //Gets the Skill Level from Slicer and converts the text to an int. Assumes Slicer Value is in "[Skill] [Level]" format. Example: "Writing 2"

var showRow = IF(
                ISEMPTY(
                    FILTER(addSkillLevel,
                        CONTAINSSTRING([Value], MAX('Skill Selection List'[Skill])) //Checks if the skill is in the Slicer Value
                        && MAX('Skill Selection List'[Level]) <= [Level] //Checks if the Slicer Skill Level is less than or equal to the Skill Section List's Level
                    )
                     )
                     ,0,1) //Returns 0 if the the criteria is not met, or 1 if the criteria is met. 1 = Show, 0 = Hide

return showRow


HI! Nick! thank you for the reply! i will try to get this solution to work
